# Generate Letter Combinations of a Phone Number

Tags: python, python-2.x, combinatorics

The task: Given a string containing digits from 2-9 inclusive, return all possible letter combinations that the number could represent.

and my solution:

```
import itertools
letters_stack = list('abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz')
keypad_dict = {}
for num in range(2, 10):
    size = 3
    if num in [7, 9]:
        size = 4
    keypad_dict[str(num)] = letters_stack[:size]
    letters_stack = letters_stack[size:]

def aux(numbers):
    if len(numbers) == 1:
        return keypad_dict[numbers[0]]
    return itertools.product(keypad_dict[numbers[0]],  iletters(numbers[1:]))    

def iletters(numbers):
    assert len(numbers) > 0
    return [''.join(x) for x in aux(numbers)]



print list(iletters('234'))
# ['adg', 'adh', 'adi', 'aeg', 'aeh', 'aei', 'afg', 'afh', 'afi', 'bdg', 'bdh', 'bdi', 'beg', 'beh', 'bei', 'bfg', 'bfh', 'bfi', 'cdg', 'cdh', 'cdi', 'ceg', 'ceh', 'cei', 'cfg', 'cfh', 'cfi']
```

Comment: Please do not update the code in your question to incorporate feedback from answers, doing so goes against the Question + Answer style of Code Review. This is not a forum where you should keep the most updated version in your question. Please see *[what you may and may not do after receiving answers](//codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1765)*.

Comment: I know. but it was actually a typo, I copied the solution from leetcode which requires a strange scaffold class

Answer (score 10):

You can set the keypad lookup as a constant instead of computing it dynamically. Setting it up as constant makes it clearer that what your intent is.

```
KEYPAD = {
    '2': 'abc',
    '3': 'def',
    '4': 'ghi',
    '5': 'jkl',
    '6': 'mno',
    '7': 'pqrs',
    '8': 'tuv',
    '9': 'wxyz'}
```

---

`itertools.product` can accept multiple lists. And in python, you can use `*` to unpack an iterable into positional arguments, and `**` to unpack as keyword arguments.

To sum up:

```
def t9_mode(numbers):
    if len(numbers) == 1:
        return KEYPAD[numbers[0]]
    maps = map(KEYPAD.get, numbers)
    return [''.join(_) for _ in itertools.product(*maps)]
```

does the job.

Answer (score 0):

Python allows indexing of strings, for instance `'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'[3]` returns `'d'`, so you don't need to turn your string into a list. I would just hardcode the keys: `keypad = {1:'abc',2:'def' ...]`. You spent more code generating `keypad_dict` than it would take to just declare it.

Having `aux` and `iletters` be programs that recursively call each other is making things way more complicated than they need to be. You can just do `[''.join(_) for _ in itertools.product(keypad[__] for __ in numbers)]`

Comment: to declare it is probably more error-prone, but it's quite subjective

Comment: >call each other
sorry, it was a typo. fixed it